# What does mean a notion of R-net?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

In the paper I am reading now I have found of notion  of R-net, but I don't know what does it mean. It is related to metric spaces. Do you know what is it?

Comment: We’ll need more context to be sure, but it’s probably a set $A$ of points such that $\bigcup_{x\in A}B(x,R)$ is the whole space. That is, every point of the space is less than $R$ units from some point of $A$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is the definition I am looking for.

Comment: Oh, good. Do you want me to make my comment an answer, or do you simply want to delete the question? Either is fine.

Comment: I want your comment to be an answer.

Comment: I’ve copied the important part of it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

It’s probably a set $A$ of points such that $\bigcup_{x\in A}B(x,R)$ is the whole space. That is, every point of the space is less than $R$ units from some point of $A$.